# How to solve "The code is missing or incomplete"? Google Adsense in Vue app

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, adsense, firebase-hosting

I built a SPA in Vue and hosted it in firebase hosting... Now I'm trying to monetize it with Google Adsense, I have to put this `<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-45537465896744582" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>` inside the `<head></head>` tags.

I already put the script inside the head tags, but when Adsense checks, it says that the code is missing or incomplete, and I don't understand why ... When I check the source code of my site, the script tag is there, I even checked the site in Mobile-Friendly Test and it also appears there.
Any ideas why Adsense can't find the script?

Comment: Do you see `googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads` request in network tab?

Comment: i have the same questions as with this, yes i receive that in my network tab